# Check if a Maven dependency has CVEs without having to include it in my project

Tags: vulnerability

In our project, we are using OWASP dependency checks to check whether a dependency has vulnerabilities or not.

How can we check if a given Maven package has a known vulnerability?

I do not want to always have to include it in my project and run the whole OWASP check before I know if I can/should add a new dependency.

Comment: Questions asking for online resources are off-topic, so I adjusted your question.

Comment: Although you can look up the package in various vulnerability databases, I don't think those searches tend to look at vulnerabilities in transitive dependencies. How long does the OWASP check take? It seems like that would be the safest course of action to prevent not only vulnerabilities in the dependency you're adding, but all transitive dependencies as well.

Comment: OWASP check itself does not take long. But we have to rebuild the whole project and this can take a bit.